# color background of plotly char in many colors between grids in R

Tags: r, background, plotly, grid

I have a problem generating a chart in Plotly that meets my expectations. I would like to generate a chart with the background colored in different colors (depending on the ranges, see an example below), and then plot the confidence interval + forecast value + real value on it.
I generated a chart with the appropriate background and the confidence interval + values separately in the second chart.
Unfortunately, I couldn't combine both solutions - sometimes one covers the other, the other time it's the other way around, and another time it's a total mix, but the effect was never what I expected - the background (the first graph) as a background, and the second one in the foreground chart (confidence interval + values)

**Background code:**

```
colorData <- data.frame(
  from = c(0,20,40,60,80),
  to   = c(20,40,60,80,100),
  color = c("#F8CBAD", "#E2EFDA", "#C6E0B4", "#FFF2CC", "#FCE4D6")
)

background_plot <- plot_ly()
for(i in c(1:nrow(colorData))){
  background_plot <- add_trace(
    background_plot, 
    x = c(colorData$from[i], colorData$to[i], colorData$to[i], colorData$from[i]),   
    y = c(-0.2, -0.2, 1.2, 1.2), 
    type = 'scattergl', 
    mode = 'lines', 
    fill = 'toself', 
    fillcolor = colorData$color[i], 
    line = list(color = 'transparent'), 
    showlegend  = FALSE
  )
}
background_plot
```

[image]
**code for foreground chart**

```
df = data.frame(
  data = Sys.Date()+c(0:99),
  id = c(1:100),
  value = runif(100)
)
df$prediction = df$value + (runif(100)-0.5)*0.1
df$upperBound = 1.2*df$prediction
df$lowerBound = 0.8*df$prediction


plot <- plot_ly(df, x = ~id, y = ~upperBound, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', line = list(color = 'transparent'), showlegend = FALSE, name = '')
plot <- plot %>% add_trace(y = ~lowerBound, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', fill = 'tonexty', fillcolor='rgba(0,100,80,0.2)', line = list(color = 'transparent'), showlegend = FALSE, name = '')
plot <- plot %>% add_trace(y = ~prediction, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', line = list(color='rgb(0,100,80)'), name = 'Prediction', showlegend = TRUE)
plot <- plot %>% add_trace(y = ~value, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', line = list(color='rgb(205, 12, 24)'), name = 'Real', showlegend = TRUE)
plot <- plot %>% layout(
  paper_bgcolor='rgb(255,255,255)', 
  plot_bgcolor='rgb(229,229,229)',
  legend = list(x = 0.01, y = 0.99),
  xaxis = list(
    title = "Timestamp", 
    gridcolor = 'rgb(255,255,255)', 
    showgrid = TRUE, 
    showline = FALSE,
    showticklabels = TRUE,
    tickcolor = 'rgb(127,127,127)',
    ticks = 'outside',
    zeroline = FALSE,
    tickmode = 'linear', 
    tick0 = 96, 
    dtick = 96
  ),
  yaxis = list(
    title = "Value",
    gridcolor = 'rgb(255,255,255)',
    showgrid = TRUE,
    showline = FALSE,
    showticklabels = TRUE,
    tickcolor = 'rgb(127,127,127)',
    ticks = 'outside',
    zeroline = FALSE)
)
plot
```

[image]

In other words, I would like to replace the `plot_bgcolor` parameter in the second code with the result of the first code.

By the way, let me ask you a second question. In the `df` responsible for generating the second chart, there are 2 columns: 1 is `date` and the other is `id`. Is it possible to display `id` values on the X axis (this is how it is now), but when I hover over the chart line, the popup will show me the corresponding value for the `date` column?

Comment: Have a look at the `shapes` parameter in plotly, especially of type `rect`: https://plotly.com/r/shapes/

Comment: @king_of_limes it works fine, thanks! Do you know, how to add legend to this shapes?

Comment: I'm not sure. There are legend and name parameters in the layout.shapes reference (https://plotly.com/r/reference/layout/shapes/), but I couldn't get them to work right now. I guess you could add fake traces with `visible = legendonly` and then create a shape exactly where those legend entries are, but that seems overly complicated.

Comment: it works as I expected :)